# Lightning component hide ui:inputText / ui:inputSelectfields based on dropdown selection

Tags: lightning-aura-components

how to hide/unhide fields and dropdowns based on a dropdown change. Right now i dynamically create or destroy those text fields and dropdown whenever the master dropdown is changed. Is there any other way i could achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead you can try aura:IF tag.

Bring all fields on page, and display only those fields that you want on master change.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_if.htm